# CSS inside "pages" in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I can put `.css` inside `pages` directory in a Next.js application and import it from my pages with `import "./my-css.css"`.

Still, is it a good practice? Will it cause routing problems, or is it simply ignored by router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#setup) it states "Every `.js` file becomes a route that gets automatically processed and rendered." It also looks possible to change what extensions are used: https://github.com/zeit/next.js#configuring-extensions-looked-for-when-resolving-pages-in-pages

So I don't think it will cause routing problems to have a `.css` file there, but I also don't think it's a good practice to put them there just because I would not expect to anything but pages in the pages folder in a nextjs app.